# Rate of convergence in an infinite geometric series of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following system

$Z=[A^t + A^{t-1}+A^{t-2}+....+I]*E$, in which $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and $Z$ and $E$ are $n\times1$ vectors. The eigenvalues of $A$ are all smaller than one and the leading eigenvalue is between $0$ and $1$. The entries of $A$ are also $0\leq a_{i,j}<1$. I know the system converge to $Z*=[(I=A)^{-1}]*E$ if $t$ is large. However I am interested in estimate the rate of convergence to $Z*$. Someone can help me out? Is there any way to estimate the rate of convergence based on the eigenvalues of $A$ or $(I-A)^{-1}$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Diagonalizing $A$ reduces this problem to convergence of geometric series of diagonal matrices, which converge at the same rate as geometric series for regular reals. The factor will be the largest non-1 eigenvalue.

Comment: @Paulo no problem.